# Flash does not have enough memory.

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I solve it? I was about to run my fla. file then one message appeared and it state that the memory was not enough. How can I solve it?

Comment: flash uses JVM underneath, so usualy this solves the problem by setting other memory limits for the underlying JVM,eg by `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xmx512M` environment parameter

Comment: @NikosM. I tried to change in jvm.ini file to 1024m but the access was denied.

Comment: actually you just set an environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` (eg in windows) with the appropriate memory limit and JVM will pick it up automaticaly